# C# binding to table, refresh form controls when data row content changes

Tags: c#, data-binding, refresh

I'm working on a handheld device using C#.Net against SqlCe database.  I have a form with multiple panels, each panel has its own group of textbox controls.  When the form is built, I auto-bind each textbox control to its matching column name from a table I query from a database.  Ex: txtFld1 = ResultTable.Fld1, txtFld2 = ResultTable.Fld2, etc.  All this works no problem.  If I query the table for a given record ID, the form refreshes no problem.  If I click on a button on the form and manually change the value of the single row in the table of one or more fields, the form does not reflect these changes...  Ex:

```
DataRow oDR = MySQLResultTable.Rows[0];
oDR["Fld1"] = "Something";
oDR["Fld2"] = "else";
oDR["Fld3"] = "changed";
```

The 3 fields on the form do not reflece these changed values.  However, if I key into the specific fields, the values are pushed back into the respective data row of the MySQLResultTable, Row[0] object.

What am I missing.

Thanks

In its simplified format since I determine the control's name and find the corresponding column name in the table, here is what I have

```
public void BindControlsToDataTable(Control Page, DataTable oTbl )
{
   String cObjName;
   foreach (Control oCtrl in Page.Controls)
   {
      // if this control has other controls, bind them too...
      if (oCtrl.Controls.Count > 0)
         BindControlsToDataTable(oCtrl, oTbl);

      // Now, try to do dynamic binding.  The controls are created
      // based on a 3 char prefix such as "txt", "cbo", "chk", etc
      // with the remainder as the object name they represent...
      // ex: txtDescription, txtFirstName, txtLastName, chkIsOk, etc..
      cObjName = oCtrl.Name.Substring(3);
      if (oTbl.Columns[lcName] != null)
      {
         oCtrl.DataBindings.Clear();
         // we are binding the "TEXT" property of the control
         // to the column name in the table/row
         oCtrl.DataBindings.Add("Text", oTbl, cObjName,true, 
             DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
      }
   }
}
```

So again, if my textbox field is txtMyFld1, and a corresponding column name in the table is MyFld1, they will be paired-up automatically.  I call this after the form is initialized and I've prepared/run my first query to populate a DataTable object and bind.

HTH

Comment: Could you add data binding initialization code to your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved... Thanks anyhow... he didnt have "MyTable.AcceptChanges()" after updating the individual columns.  The AcceptChanges() actually flushes the changes back to the bound TO source control.